# Jquery Malsup Form Plugin errors in IE for file upload

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have been searching for the last 2 days trying to find a solution to this problem.

there are quite a few issues with the file upload of the Malsup form plugin for jquery - mostly surrounding the use of .click() functions. However I managed to work those out, but now I am trying to implement the progress bar.

It works fine in Chrome/FF but in IE I am getting the same error as before - basically the plugin gets stuck at the form.submit() part.

Can you please try loading the demo page in IE and see if you can figure out the problem?
http://jquery.malsup.com/form/progress.html

I noticed it was missing 2 semi-colons (2 different locations) after bar.width(percentVal)
but even with them in it doesn't work.

Also, if you run the demo page with IE developer tool running, it freezes at the form.submit() part. If you don't use that, the progress bar doesn't animate but the file does seem to upload since it returns the name of the file.....

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with IE. After some googling I found out that upload progress is only supported
with XHR uploads on Chrome, FF,
Safari and IE10.

http://caniuse.com/xhr2

https://github.com/malsup/form/issues/177